# How to check easily the munin alert-email-notification?

Tags: debian, exim, munin

I run the munin monitoring application on my debian Wheezy server and I would like to test the alert-email-notification procedure.
To do that, I add in munin.conf the following line:

```
df._home.warning 25
```

I set 25 because the df command returns 30 for /home.

I also defined one contact:

```
contacts me
contact.me.command mail "munin test ${var:host}" my_email@my_isp.com
```

Unfortunately I don't receive any mails.

There are no errors in the logs.
Note that I use exim4 to send emails and that I can send emails from a terminal.

What could be wrong in my configuration ?

Note also I ckecked manually the df plugin:

```
munin-run df
```

returns 30 for /home

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but I stumbled upon this looking for a way to debug/force email notifications for testing.

I think the `mail` command is missing `-s` to indicate the subject:

```
contact.me.command mail "munin test ${var:host}" my_email@my_isp.com
```

should be

```
contact.me.command mail -s "munin test ${var:host}" my_email@my_isp.com
```

I found these commands really helpful:

- To debug configuration ([ref](https://www.agix.com.au/troubleshooting-munin-server/)):

```
sudo -u munin /usr/share/munin/munin-update --debug
```

- To test and force notification ([ref](https://www.agix.com.au/munin-server-how-to-force-emails-to-be-sent/)):

```
sudo -u munin /usr/share/munin/munin-limits --contact my_email@my_isp.com --force
```

I hope that's helpful.